# Colorbar for barplot when bar colors are selected by ranks

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, colorbar

I am trying  to produce barplot where colors of bars will be chosen according to given values from predefined set of colors. The "pahse" value determines the color. It is splitted into 3 ranges and ranges are ranked. Rank is used to call a colorfrom palette. This part works fine. But I stuck with colorbar. Colorbar should contain colors based on keys of the dictionary "rank_classes" and tiks/labels based on values what were used for ranking. I tried matplotlib's  mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(), but it does not seem to like seaborns sns.cubehelix_palette(). I wonder how to put these two things to work together or there more straightforward solutions?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("white")
#%matplotlib inline

index = ['25', '26', '27']
count = [10, 50, 22]
phase = [0.9, 2.2, 1.2]
ranks = [0, 2, 1]

rank_classes = {0:"Ph<1", 1:"1<Ph<1.2", 2:"Ph>=1.2"}

d = {'count' : pd.Series(count, index=index),
     'phase' : pd.Series(phase, index=index),
     'rank'  : pd.Series(ranks, index=index)
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# barplot 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pal = sns.cubehelix_palette(3) 

x = df.index
y = list(df['count'])
z = list(df['rank'])

sns.barplot(x=x, y=y, palette=np.array(pal)[z])
sns.despine()
```

Comment: Do you mean like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31313606/pyplot-matplotlib-bar-chart-with-fill-color-depending-on-value?

Comment: @lanery 
I see, the trick is to plot two figures on a top of each other and from scatter plot show colorbar only. In my case I have two problems with adapting referred code for my needs. 

First, I'd like to use seaborn color scheme with predefined number of colors  like **sns.cubehelix_palette(3)** . But this format is not compatible with cmap in plt.scatter() . How to make it compatible?

Second, How to assign predefined string labels ("A", "B", "Z") for  first, second, etc ...  colors in **sns.cubehelix_palette(3)** using **plt.colobar()**?

Answer (score 1):

Almost there

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("white")
%matplotlib inline

index = ['25', '26', '27']
count = [10, 50, 22]
phase = [0.9, 2.2, 1.2]
rank  = [0, 2, 1]
# 
rank_classes = {0:"Ph<1", 1:"1<Ph<1.2", 2:"Ph>=1.2"}

pal = sns.cubehelix_palette(len(index)) 
cmp = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_list', pal,\
                                                    N=len(index))
plot = plt.scatter(index, count, c=range(len(index)), cmap=cmp)
plt.clf()
plt.colorbar(plot)
sns.barplot(x=index, y=count, palette=np.array(pal)[rank])
sns.despine()
```

Produces nice plot with colorbar. Only thing I have to figure out is how to replace colorbar's number labels (0, 0.3 ...3.0) with strings listed in the dictionary **rank_classes**.

[image: Bar plot with colobar]

Comment: Finally managed to get what I needed based on:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831569/matplotlib-pyplot-colorbar-question
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908371/matplotlib-colorbars-and-its-text-labels